# inverse task of tessellation

Tags: algorithm, 3d, computational-geometry

As input I have a set of triangles that form concave mesh with holes. Each triangle consist of three vertices: (vi,vj,vk),... No adjacency information is provided. Algorithm have to "union" the set of triangles with the **same normal** into polygon. So output is (pi,pj,pk,...,ps),...

For example(see picture below), let say we have mesh that consist of triangles

(v0,v1,v4), (v1,v3,v4), (v1,v2,v3)

(v2,v6,v4), (v6,v5,v4).

As output we have:

(p0,p1,p4)

(p1,p2,p3,p4)

[image]

I'm looking for efficient algorithm that solves problem described above. Any suggestion, tips or articles is appreciated.

Comment: by `same normals` are you referring to triangle normals (or direction and magnitude of steepest descent) rather than vertex normals in this context?  My guess is that you are looking for points on the output polygon to be more or less co-planar which would indicate the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at adaptive mesh coarsening algorithms. These are typically used in advanced software for Computational Fluid Dynamics ([Ansys CFX](http://www.ansys.com/Products/Simulation+Technology/Fluid+Dynamics/ANSYS+CFX), [CD-Adapco Star CCM+](http://www.cd-adapco.com/products/star_ccm_plus/index.html) etc.) / Structural Dynamics (Anasys et al.). Where automatic refinement and coarsening of a given mesh is advantageous.

Some free papers to look at on this subject, that will give you a strong starting point are:

1. https://cfwebprod.sandia.gov/cfdocs/CCIM/docs/coarsening.pdf
2. http://tetra.mech.ubc.ca/ANSLab/publications/coarsen.pdf
3. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/MiTaTe98.pdf (This is fairly mathematical)

Additional Google searches in the area of adaptive mesh refinement algorithms will reveal similar papers on the subject.

Edit. A basic and well established method for the adaptive mesh coarsing is the *Edge Collapse Method* which involves reducing an edge to a single vertex and thereby removing two elements. Li X., Shephard M.S., Beall M.W. “3-D anisotropic mesh adaptation by mesh modifications.” Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering, 2004. has a great coarsening algorithm which is defined in pseudo-code as

```
for all edge in short edge list do
    for all vertex that bounds the current edge do
        if vertex is not yet tagger then
            append vertex to dynamic list
            tag vertex to be in dynamic list
        end if
    end for
end for
while vertices not tagged processed in dynamic list do
    get an unprocessed vertex Vi from the list
    get Ej , the shortest mesh edge in transformed space connected to Vi
    if the transformed length Ej is greater than Llow then
        remove Vi from the dynamic list
    else
        evaluate edge collapse operation of collapsing Ej with Vi removed
        if the edge collapse would create an edge longer than Lmax then
            evaluate relocated vertex Vi
        else if the edge collapse would lead to 
            at/inverted elements then
            evaluate the swaps(s)/collapse compound operation
        end if
        if any local mesh modication is determined then
            tag neighbouring vertices of Vi in the dynamic list as unprocessed
            apply the local mesh modication
            remove Vi from the dynamic list if it is collapse
        else
            tag Vi as processed
        end if
    end if
end while
```

This is taken from an impressive Masters thesis I have used in the past. It can be found [here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/teaching/distinguished-projects/2011/m.potter.pdf)

I hope this helps.

Comment: is there any easier solution? :)

Comment: To do this process in a logical, efficent and correct manner is inevitably complex. In fact, there are Ph.D.s avalible on this subject. How big is the mesh you are dealing with?

Comment: this problem comes from CAD. so, meshes can be very large.

Comment: Although, Shane's answer below seems logical, the approach he outlines is not complete and will not quite be satisfactory for what you want. Firstly to establish what type of poloygon you will use for the selection criteria will be difficult and there are other issues with the outlined approach as well. One method I have used in the past is the Edge and Element collapse method. I will update my answer with the pseudo code for this method and a reference...

Comment: @Killercam, I'm not sure this even is a mesh coarsening problem.  I'd see it more as a clustering problem, where the object is to cluster triangles with the same normal and then draw the outline of each cluster.  The only reason I'm decomposing polygons which are already triangles is based on the v1-v3 edge in the original diagram, which would otherwise leave the edge v2-v6-v4 with two neighbours on the v4-v2 edge.  i.e. the original input does constitute a well formed TIN.  I wouldn't consider this an overly complex problem.

Comment: Also, your pseudocode appears to deal with edges.  I don't see any reference to `same normals` which I'd take as being triangle normals (or direction and magnitude of steepest descent) rather than vertex normals in this context.  I could well be wrong here, the term should possibly be clarified in the question.

Comment: The is definitely a mesh coarsening problem. The OP has confirmed this by stating that it is to do with the coarsening of a CAD unstructured tetrahedral mesh, and yes, this problem is a relatively complex one (if you want to do it with relative accuracy and without the production of  _bad cells_). One complexity to contend with is the creation of cells with poor orthogonally, inadequate _skewness_ and aspect ratios. These things are important if you want a good quality mesh with which to do analysis.

Comment: Also note, the down vote is not warranted what-so-ever. I _was_ a CFD specialist working in the nuclear and defence industry. I have written mesh creation and adaptive refinement tools myself in FORTRAN and C++ for my research in Relativistic MHD and in industry. @ShaneMacLaughlin read the previous comments regarding the CAD reference; also note that the pseudo code is an _example_ of a very well-known approach to the problem in hand - and an example of the approach that _should_ be used, not necessarily one that will fix his current code or attempt at the problem.

Comment: @Killercam, perhaps you could explain why the OP _should_ use an approach that will not necessarily fix his problem? You're introducing straw men like _bad_ _cells_ and _selection_ _criteria_ without qualifying them, I don't think either are relevant to the question, in what appears to be an attempt to add complexity to a problem that simply doesn't exist.  FWIW I down voted your answer because I believe it is wrong.   Prior experience in the nuclear or defence industries doesn't really change that.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin "this problem comes from CAD. so, meshes can be very large.". This itself shows clearly that the issue is to do with geometrical meshing. To coarsen a 3D unstructured mesh (which is exactly what this is), **IS** a complex matter to do well. I am not here to write an algoritm for the guy. I have provided references to everything I have said and shown what more do you want. The words I have used are also _not_ "straw men" but important factors in mesh creation.

Comment: ... To say "add complexity to a problem that simply doesn't exist" is silly - I am telling you (someone with no experience in the area) that the problem is a complex one if it is to be done right (providing all the neccessary reading for the OP). You might try climing down of that horse and reading some of them to convince yourself...

Comment: @Killercam, my current favourite references for the mesh and TIN end of computational geometry are _Hjelle_ _&_ _Deahlen_, _Edelsbrunner_, _O_Rourke_, and _Shamos_ _&_ _Perparata_  I don't see the term _bad_ _cell_ appear in the indices of any of them.  Please feel free to enlighten me further on how much experience I have in this area, or perhaps you somehow believe adding ad hominem attacks your list of fallacious arguments will somehow support your position.

Comment: @innochenti, possibly worth noting that an answer such as the above, which replaces edges with single vertices, can have undesirable side effects such as changing the area and geometry of the data.  Replacing a series of adjacent triangles which are co-planar with a polygon describing their convex hull does not have these effects.  I've been critical of this answer primarily for this reason, but also for the reason that the poster is misleading you in terms of the complexity.  Conflating adjacent triangles to form polygons based on a given criterion is not rocket science.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head;

- Triangulate each polygon, to get a set of triangles.
- For all triangles in all polygons, assign a group number based on the normal
- For every triangle T = (va,vb,vc) created the adjacency information E = (ab,bc,ca) where ab is a link / index to the triangle adjacent to T at edge a,b.
- Trace the outline of each new polygon by searching for any edge where the two neighbouring triangles are not part of the same group, following to the next edge with the same relationship, and repeating until you get back to the first edge.

Note you will also have to contend with a NULL edge type at the edge of your TIN hull, but this is straightforward.

The slowest bit here is developing the adjacency information which can be done in O(n log n) by many good TIN creation algorithms.